# Show that a space is closed using nets

Tags: general-topology

I have the set $X = \{f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1] : f \text{ is non decresing i.e. } x \leq y \Rightarrow f(x) \leq f(y) \} \subset [0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$ with the subspace topology unduced from the product topology. How can I show that X is closed using nets?

I was thinking if I have a convergent net $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ where $f_i \in X$ which converge to $f$ then I want to show that for $x\leq y$ we have $f(x) \leq f(y)$. I was thinking some kind of estimation $f(y) - f(x) \geq \ ? \ \geq 0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that that $(f_i)_{i \in I} \to g$ where $f_i \in X$. We want to show that $g \in X$. Assume, for contradiction, that $g \not \in X$. Then, there exists $x_1, x_2$ such that $x_1 < x_2$ and $g(x_1) > g(x_2)$. Now, let $g(x_1) > b > g(x_2)$.  Let $U_b = \{f \in [0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}: f(x_1) >b\} \cap \{f \in [0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}: f(x_2) <b\} $. Now, $U_b$ is the intersection of two basic opens and therefore it is open in $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$. Notice that $g \in U$. However, $X \cap U = \emptyset$. Therefore, $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ does not converge to $g$ (since our net fails to meet every open set containing $g$) and we have a contradiction.